# Powershell runspace instantiate error: System.Management.Automation not found

Tags: powershell, asp.net-core, exchange-server, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

I am trying to make some remote requests to Exchange from a .NET core api but I am having some issues and I am unable to find a solution.

I created a singleton pattern so I can only have one powershell session per user and whenever I have to make  a call to exchange I retrive that session. The problem is that I get an System.IO.FileNotFoundException' en System.Management.Automation.dll error when I try to create the runspace and I cannot run any command.

I am hosting my api in a local IIS in Windows 10 and I use .NET Core 2.2.  If  i make a request direcctly to the IIS Express, when running my code in Visual Studio, I get no error but I do get the exception when I make the request to the IIS site.

Any help will be appreciated!!!

Thank you!!!

I tried to create the runspace locally and connect to Exchange but I also tried to connect remotelly and save that configuration so I would only have to import the session.

We also tried to update the .net core to 3 version but we had no luck.

```
// this is how I retrive the sessíon from the singleton --
public Powershell GetSession(string usuario, string password)
{
    PSCredential credenciales = Powershell.CrearCredenciales(usuario, password);
    Powershell powershell;
    if (diccionarioSesionesPowershell.ContainsKey(credenciales))
    {
        powershell = diccionarioSesionesPowershell[credenciales];
        bool sesionValida = powershell.EsValida();
        if (!sesionValida)
        {
            powershell.InicializarRunspace();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        powershell = new Powershell(credenciales, Logger);
        powershell.CrearRunspace();
        diccionarioSesionesPowershell.Add(credenciales, powershell);
    }
    return powershell;
}





// this is the singleton config in startup
services.AddSingleton<PilaPowershell>();




// this is how I save my remote session so I can import it later
private Runspace Runspace{get; set;}

public bool InicializarRunspace()
{
    bool resultado = false;
    try
    {
        Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();-->this is where I get the error
        Runspace.Open();

        // Create a powershell session for remote exchange server
        using (var powershell = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            var command = new PSCommand();
            command.AddCommand("New-PSSession");
            command.AddParameter("ConfigurationName", "Microsoft.Exchange");
            command.AddParameter("ConnectionUri", new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/"));
            command.AddParameter("Authentication", "Basic");
            command.AddParameter("Credential", Credenciales);
            powershell.Commands = command;
            powershell.Runspace = Runspace;

            var result = powershell.Invoke();
            SesionesPS = result[0];
        }

        // Set ExecutionPolicy on the process to unrestricted
        using (var powershell = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            var command = new PSCommand();
            command.AddCommand("Set-ExecutionPolicy");
            command.AddParameter("Scope", "Process");
            command.AddParameter("ExecutionPolicy", "Unrestricted");
            powershell.Commands = command;
            powershell.Runspace = Runspace;

            powershell.Invoke();
        }

        // Import remote exchange session into runspace
        using (var powershell = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            var command = new PSCommand();
            command.AddCommand("Import-PSSession");
            command.AddParameter("Session", SesionesPS);
            powershell.Commands = command;
            powershell.Runspace = Runspace;

            powershell.Invoke();
        }
        resultado = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.LogError(ex, "Powershell error when creating runspace: ");
        resultado = false;
    }
    return resultado;
}





//this is how I try to create the runspace and connect remotelly - I do open and close the runspace when I run my commands
public void CrearRunspace()
{
    WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri(LiveId), SchemaUri, Credenciales);
    connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic;
    Runspace =  RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);-->this is where I get the error
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to add `Using System.Management.Automation` to your code? And then also add the `System.Management.Automation.dll` as a reference Assembly.

Comment: @RohinSidharth thank you for your answer. I do have the using statement and the references but still no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my problem. When I created the api I downloaded the powershell sdk with nuget but when I published it with that SDK, IIS could not access the dependecies needed. So I uninstalled the SDK and instead I installed powershell 6 on my PC and linked the dependencies in the assembly and it worked!!